# What is the purpose of System.Drawing.Common in comparison to for example System.Drawing?

Tags: c#, winforms

I recently downloaded `System.Drawing.Common v8.0.1` through NuGet to my Visual Studio 2022 but for the life of me I can't seem to figure out what functionalities downloading it has added to my Visual Studio 2022.

There has been no new `using` references or anything else that I have noticed. Am I blind?

What does `System.Drawing.Common` have that standard `System.Drawing` doesn't? Are they the same thing? Why would it be separately downloadble package in that case?

The GitHub page hasn't been helpful. Could someone elaborate? Give some useful links? Maybe give an example or two of what can be done with `System.Drawing.Common` that cannot be done with just `System.Drawing`.

Comment: Show us your `.csproj` and tell us more about your project.

Comment: `System.Drawing.Commom` is the library the substitutes `System.Drawing` in .NET. Just Write `[Graphics].SomeMethod()` and press F12

Answer (score 1):

It's important to understand the difference between types, namespaces and assemblies. It's also important to learn how to use the .NET documentation.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0) is the documentation page for the `Graphics` class in .NET 8. As you can see, the class is a member of the `System.Drawing` namespace and is declared in the *System.Drawing.dll* assembly.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics?view=netframework-4.8.1) is the documentation page for the `Graphics` class in .NET Framework 4.8.1. As you can see, the class is a member of the `System.Drawing` namespace and is declared in the *System.Drawing.Common.dll* assembly.

So, what are you actually talking about in your question? The same class is a member of the same namespace - `System.Drawing` - in both cases, so there's no difference from that perspective. *System.Drawing.Common* is a Nuget package and *System.Drawing.Common.dll* is an assembly. The assembly is part of the package and the class that is a member of the namespace is declared in that assembly.

The .NET Framework was composed of many assemblies but .NET Core (.NET 5 and later are based on .NET Core) has rearranged many of those and also split many of them into multiple smaller assemblies. For instance, *System.Data.dll* contained the `SqlClient`, `OleDb` and `Odbc` ADO.NET providers in .NET Framework but .NET Core has separate assemblies for each one. The types they contain are still the same (other than some new features in some cases) but they have simply been rearranged. The same goes for types in the `System.Drawing` namespace.

You should have read the NuGet documentation too. The *System.Drawing.Common* package says this:

> Provides access to GDI+ graphics functionality.
>
> Commonly Used Types:
>
> System.Drawing.Bitmap
>
> System.Drawing.BitmapData
>
> System.Drawing.Brush
>
> System.Drawing.Font
>
> System.Drawing.Graphics
>
> System.Drawing.Icon

There is also a *System.Drawing.Primitives* package that says this:

> Provides basic drawing primitive structures, that exposes the corresponding System.Drawing.dll types in .NET Core.
>
> Commonly Used Types:
>
> System.Drawing.Point
>
> System.Drawing.PointF
>
> System.Drawing.Size
>
> System.Drawing.SizeF
>
> System.Drawing.Rectangle
>
> System.Drawing.RectangleF

They presumably did this so you could use the primitive types without having the extra weight of the common types if you didn't need them. I haven't checked but I'd assume that the primitives package is a dependency of the common package.

Comment: "*You should have read the NuGet documentation too.*" Can you link to this documentation? Especially since you quote it a couple of times in the answer.

Comment: @TylerH, in order to do that, I would have to open the NuGet site and search for the relevant package. Anyone using this site is presumably of the opinion that they have the potential to be able to write software, so I'm going to assume that they are capable of doing that for themselves, if they need it. Users here should not need help with basic internet usage, including using a search engine.

Comment: not only did you already presumably do that to get the quotes in the first place, but citing your sources is also a *requirement* here per site rules.